# Implementing a foreign trait for all implementors of a local trait in rust

Tags: generics, rust, traits, orphan-rule

I have some local types, say

```rust
struct A;
struct B;
```

which all implement a local trait `MyTrait`:

```rust
pub trait MyTrait { }

impl MyTrait for A { }
impl MyTrait for B { }
```

Now I want to implement a standard library trait for both `A` and `B`, generically:

```rust
impl<T: MyTrait> ToString for T {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

However, due to the orphan rule, this is not allowed:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)
 --> src/main.rs:9:6
  |
9 | impl<T: MyTrait> ToString for T {
  |      ^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
  |
  = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local
  = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

Is there a way to make this work (except macros) and if so, how? It need to implement the trait for these specific types, not some wrapper type.

Comment: Rust doesn't allow this. There could be a type `Foo` that already implements `ToString`. If it tries to implement `MyTrait`, then implementations would conflict. You'll have to add the `ToString` implementation for each type manually. BTW, you should usually implement `Display` instead of `ToString`.

Comment: There is a proposal for a feature called "sealed traits", which would enforce that a local trait as you call it can only be implemented in the current trait, that would allow what you are asking for.

Comment: I already love rust, but sometimes I wish it was 10 years from now and I could use rust without occasionally bumping into some incomplete feature

Comment: @jthulhu If I recall correctly, the current proposal for sealed traits does not make (and disallows) these coherency modifications, but it talks about the possibility that some future proposal will add a different mechanism for sealed traits that will affect coherency.

Comment: @Einliterflasche No programming languages covers 100% of the use cases with 100% convenience. Just accept it (and in this case, use a macro). It doesn't mean the language or its features are incomplete (there are some features that I can accept being called incomplete, but I don't think coherency is one of them).

Comment: @Einliterflasche on the other hand, that makes you living in a very exciting time!